# Is it object, or array? Which one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

A colleague, by mistake wrote this code:

```
var parameters = [];
// some lengthy code here
parameters.firstParameter = "first parameter value";
parameters.secondParameter = "second parameter value";
```

He had declared `parameters` variable as an array, but somewhere else he had used it as an object, adding parameters to it.

The results of testing the type of this parameter is as follow (in Google Chrome's console):

```
parameters;
// prints []

typeof parameters;
// prints "object"

parameters instanceof Array;
// prints true
```

So, is it an object or an array at last? Or does it have a dual nature, both array and object at the same time?

Comment: In JavaScript pretty much *everything* is an object, and can have properties; hence `[object Array]`, `[object Object]`...

Comment: @DavidThomas And every object is also an array, in a manner of speaking (you can address its elements using an indexer). More importantly, why do you care? What observable difference between the two are you expecting?

Comment: @Luaan: true of course, I never thought to add that though. :)

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript *everything* is an **Object**. If you define an Array so it'll be treat as an object in JavaScript. Since it is an object, you can access properties associated to it.

Comment: Any reference for that claim that *everything* is an object?

Comment: Well, not [**everything**](http://www.2ality.com/2011/03/javascript-values-not-everything-is.html) is an object. Among other things `null` is not.

Comment: And none of the primitives are objects. (Common misconception, because JS automatically turns them into objects as soon as you try to use them as objects.)

Comment: And in modern browsers, more limitations are appearing all the time. For example, in Chrome, `var pom = 23; pom.myTest = "Hi"; alert(pom.myTest);` will give `undefined`.

Comment: In JS objects are bit different from what we see in languages likes C#, C++ or Java. An object in JS is simply a hashmap with key-value pairs. A key is always a string, and a value can be anything including strings, integers, booleans, functions, other objects etc